# Digital alternative to hand analyzed maps

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

I am a staunch believer in the benefit of hand analyzing maps to get a good feel for the state of the atmosphere before getting into my forecast. With Covid-19 keeping us out of the office, one of the things I miss the most is being able to print out maps and hand analyze them.

Does anyone have any tips for analyzing maps without printing them out or alternatives to a hand analysis that you have had good experiences with?

Comment: Retro-engineering plots and maps ... sounds like WebPlotDigitizer (https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) even if the developer's later walk-through (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7GbGdMvopU, 12:58min) is about distances on a topographic map.

Comment: Why not use something like MS paint?

Comment: What is the file format of the digital maps?  Knowing that would help us identify appropriate software.